# Why exactly is \linespread{1.05} appropriate for Palatino?

Tags: fonts, typography, line-spacing, mathpazo

Section 1.4 of [l2tabu](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/l2tabu/english/l2tabuen.pdf), *Changing inter-line space using `\baselinestretch`*, contains a remark about the Palatino font:

> [I]f you only want to use fonts other than Computer Modern you may use `\linespread{<factor>}`. For example, when using Palatino `\linespread{1.05}` would be appropriate.

A factor of 1.05 for Palatino is also recommended in, e.g., [this](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/msg/bc0390b730b348ee) posting at `comp.text.tex` and (by implication) in section 2.1 *Fundamentals of Page Layout* of the [KOMA-Script manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf).

A possible reasoning is that the increased `\linespread` compensates for Palatino's larger x-height (height of lowercase letters without ascenders) and hereby avoids "cramped" text lines.

Palatino's x-height is about 9% larger than that of Computer Modern (4.69pt v. 4.31pt for a fontsize of 10pt, see MWE below). That is, the "recommended" Palatino `\linespread` factor of +5% is about half as large as the difference in x-height.

I'd like to know the following:

- Who exactly came up with `\linespread{1.05}` for Palatino? The authors of `l2tabu` or someone else?
- Is the factor of +5% just a rule of thumb, or is it the result of some (unknown to me) established typographic formula?

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Computer Modern's x-height: \the\fontdimen5\font

\fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont

Palatino's x-height: \the\fontdimen5\font

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't remember where I've seen 1.05 for the first time. I don't think there's a "rule" either. For example, if the language is German, even 1.08 might be a choice, because of the abundance of uppercase letters.

Comment: The 1.05 probably comes from whoever made the first package for using Palatino with LaTeX (the now obsolete `palatino` package), i.e. Walter Schmidt.

Comment: @Martin: Can you point me to a version of `palatino.sty` or `mathpazo.sty` that contains `\linespread{1.05}`? (The current version of `mathpazo.sty` doesn't.)

Comment: There is no (mathematical) rule for this. The general rule is that the wider the `\textwidth`, the larger the `\baselineskip`. Also the larger the x-height, the larger the `\baselineskip`. The combination of line width and leading should make sure 1) the reader can find the next line easily 2) the reader can follow the current line without distracted by following lines. The relations between x-height and leading is more arguably. Some types are designed to be "economically", they look not too bad if you set them in long lines and relatively small leading, while their x-height is also large.

Comment: @egreg: I think your observation that text set in a language that has more uppercase letters and/or more diacritics and accents applies to what should be the "correct" amount of interline space in general, regardless of the font in use (unless the font have wildly different cap heights, say). As such, it's a matter that's distinct from how to adjust the linestretch parameter in order to keep the same typographic color when switching between fonts. Would you agree?

Comment: @YanZhou: I think your observation about the relationship between line length and the appropriate amount of leading is very important. However, does it speak to the question how one should adjust the linestretch factor when switching from one font to another (while keeping all other factors -- including language being typeset, line lengths, etc.) constant?

Comment: @Mico the answer is yes and np. In typography there are only principles or guidelines you should be aware of. There are no rules you can follow exactly. Your eyes are only judges here to determine whether or not the line stretch is good or not. The point here is that, if you fix the line width, and if the leading is too small, you are more likely to be distracted by the next line (we won't read things exactly in horizontal direction.) on the other hand if it is too big, when you finish the current line, you are likely to have difficulty find the next, as it is too far away.

Comment: @Mico It's not just a question of color; one can choose Palatino *because* it's darker than CM. The `\linespread` method is too coarse when dealing with size changing problems: it's not automatic that, with Palatino set 10/12.6 for the main text, it's right at 9/11.6 for quotations (`\small`) or 8/10.5 for footnotes. But that would require writing a very detailed specification based on `size10.clo`.

Comment: @YanZhou: I read your follow-up comment as pointing out that there are typographical considerations, such as achieving and maintaining good readability, that outweigh any concerns over maintaining a given amount of color. Hence, one might have to limit the increase in the linespread factor (and thus allow an increase the color) when switching from CM to Palatino so as not to reduce the text's readability. I certainly will not and cannot disagree with this view.

Comment: @Mico I think "readability" does not "outweigh" any concerns concerns. I believe that the considerations of colors actually should serves the purpose of readability. After all, all typographical considerations should serve the purpose of the text. If the texts are meant to be read, then the color, the font, all things should serve this purpose. If the texts are meant to be displayed, then everything serve this purpose and readability is not so important anymore. The purpose of the texts is the core to everything. Typography considerations are the tool not the goal.

Comment: @egreg: I fully agree (naturally) with the view that some (many?) may find CM's color too light and hence will consciously choose Palatino; in such a case, they would definitely *not* want to increase the linespread by, say, 5 to 8%. Your second point, about how changing a given font's size will also affect a paragraph's color unless the linespread is changed nonlinearly, is also well taken. That said, it's a bit tangential (and this is not meant to be a criticism!) to the OP's question about how/why to adjust the linespread when switching from CM to Palatino in order to maintain color, right?

Comment: This seems to be somewhat of a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3711/627

Comment: While proofreading with tired eyes, I accidentally discovered another factor besides capitals and accents that may make 1.08 better than 1.05: in a document with many single quotes, the commas in one line were distracting me from the single quotes in the next.  That wouldn’t happen with most fonts, but given the shape of the quotes in Palatino, I kept losing my place until I increased the linespread to 1.08.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Some preliminary remarks. I think we can all agree that there can be no universally agreed-upon *optimal* amount of "typographic color" or "overall grayness" of a page of text. What some might consider to be "good color" may strike others as unpleasantly light, or too dark. Nevertheless, for the sake of the argument, let's assume that (i) there is an optimal amount of color and (ii) the settings for 10pt Computer Modern set "single-spaced" achieve this optimal amount. (By the way, this does *not* imply that the optimal distance between consecutive lines is 10pt for text set in CM. The topic of what exactly constitutes "single-spacing" is a matter for a different discussion.)

The question then becomes: how does one achieve this amount of color when switching to a different (text) font, such as Palatino? Palatino and CM obviously differ in many respects. Not only are their x-heights different, but so are their cap-heights and ascender heights as well as the average stroke width (to name just a couple of additional factors). The upshot is that if text that consists of a group of paragraphs is set both in Palatino and in CM with the same nominal point size (say, 10pt) and the same interline distance (say, 12pt), the paragraphs and pages set in Palatino will look noticeably darker. I think most will agree that the Palatino paragraphs will be "too dark" -- again, assuming that the text set in CM have "correct color".

> - Who exactly came up with \linespread{1.05} for Palatino? The authors of l2tabu or someone else?
> - Is the factor of +5% just a rule of thumb, or is it the result of some (unknown to me) established typographic formula?

Regarding your first question: I have no idea who was the first to come up with this recommendation. Most likely, though, the need to increase the "leading" when typesetting text in Palatino was "discovered" immediately after people started mixing/matching Palatino and CM.

The +5% recommendation you noted in the `l2tabu` document can be nothing more than a rule of thumb. My understanding is that it should be understood as a "lower bound" on the required line spread adjustment, rather than as a single number. The code below generates two half-pages of text; the upper half is in `Latin Modern`, the lower is in `Palatino nova` with a linespread factor of 1.05. (Both texts are set with nominal font sizes of 10pt, and the text itself is the usual lipsum stuff...) To my eyes at least, the text set in Palatino still has more color than the CM reference text despite the 5% adjustment. Playing with the line spacing setting, I'd say that ca. 7% achieves equal color.

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}
\frenchspacing\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{setspace,lipsum}

\begin{document}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\emph{Latin Modern}

\lipsum[1-3]

\vspace{1in}
\setmainfont{Palatino nova Regular}
\setstretch{1.05}
\emph{Palatino, linespread 1.05}

\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Add some inline math! IMHO this is one of the main reasons that one needs to adjust the linespread for palatino.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: I see your comment as advocating an increase in linespread even beyond 1.07 when using Palatino, right?

Comment: not really more caveat emptor:)

Answer (score 10):

Quoting Martin Schröder's comment:

> The 1.05 probably comes from whoever made the first package for using Palatino with LaTeX (the now obsolete `palatino` package), i.e. Walter Schmidt.

I wasn't able to locate a version of `palatino.sty` that contains `\linespread{1.05}`, but Walter Schmidt indeed suggested this factor in a [posting](http://groups.google.com/group/de.comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/53315c1a66dcdbba/) at `de.comp.text.tex` in March 2002. Here's my translation of the relevant parts:

> The reasonable value depends on the width of the text line. \linespread{1.05} is a sound reference point. Try smaller and larger values, up to about 1.08, and you'll see what is best for readability.

`\linespread{1.05}` for Palatino is also recommended in the German version of [lshort](http://ctan.org/pkg/lshort-german), co-authored by Walter Schmidt (but not in the adapted [English](http://ctan.org/pkg/lshort-english) version).

Comment: Interesting that the English and German versions of "lshort" use different values. IMHO is on purpose as one has more accented characters in German. Also I think for mathematical texts using a lot of inline math one should use 1.10.