# Setting the right linespread for kpfonts

Tags: fonts, line-spacing, kpfonts

Is this the right `linespread` for `kpfonts`?

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{nomath,oldstylenums,oldstyle,noamsmath,notextcomp}{kpfonts}
\RequirePackage{kpfonts}
\linespread{1}
```

Comment: There is no right or wrong baseline skip (as long as the adjustment is moderate). Just experiment. In a work of mine I use `\linespread{1.05}`. Why are you using `\PassOptionsToPackage` and not `\usepackage[<options>]{kpfonts}`? Note that using `\RequirePackage` is recommended only for classes or packages and that it has the same syntax as `\usepackage`.

Comment: @egreg i'm trying to write a new package for customize `classicthesis`, like the `arsclassica` package... i have read that for the `mathpazo` package the correct `linespread` is 1.05 so i have thought that for every different font exist a correct `linespread`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`kpfonts` features an x-height (height of lowercase letters like "x") of about 4.41pt (for a font size of 10pt), which is only marginally larger than that of Computer Modern (4.31pt) and smaller that that of Palatino (4.69pt). Therefore -- and if `\linespread{1.05}` suits your taste for Palatino (see [Why exactly is \linespread{1.05} appropriate for Palatino?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31064/why-exactly-is-linespread1-05-appropriate-for-palatino)) -- I suggest to try `\linespread{1.01}` for `kpfonts` (or just to leave the default settings).