# Having 1.5 linespacing except for the title page

Tags: line-spacing

Hey i would like to use `\linespread{1.5}` for a simple `1.5x` linespacing. Unfortunately this breaks the templates title pages. Is there a simple solution for this?

Those pages age build like this:

```
\begin{titlepage}
\oddsidemargin=\evensidemargin\relax
  \textwidth=\dimexpr\paperwidth-2\evensidemargin-2in\relax
  \hsize=\textwidth\relax

  \centering

  \vspace{5mm}
  {\huge\MakeUppercase{\getFaculty{}}}\\

  \vspace{5mm}
  {\large\MakeUppercase{\getUniversity{}}}\\
\end{titlepage}
```

And then called with `\input{pages/title}` in the main.tex under `\frontmatter{}`. Then there comes `\mainmatter{}` with my chapters. Could I use the linespread command only for this part somehow?

Right now there is a `\linespread{1.05}` in my settings.tex and I guess it has some purpose, too. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Yes, you can. Note onehalf spacing is not *exactly* `\linespread{1.5}`. I advise you load `setspace`, use this directive (or `\setstretch{1.5}` if you absolutely want to), as it takes care of footnotes and some other details that `\linespread` does not take into account.

Comment: Welcome! Note that if the problem is a conflict with your 'template', we can't possibly help as we don't have a minimal example to compile to reproduce the problem. If @Bernard's suggestion doesn't help, we need a complete example to be of further help. Also, what does 'breaks the templates title pages' mean?

Comment: Thanks for answering :)
@Bernard where should i put the setspace so it only affects the main part?

Comment: @cfr my template is basicly https://github.com/fwalch/tum-thesis-latex and by breaking i mean, that the logo or some text of the title pages gets shifted to the next page

Comment: `\setspace{1.5}` should be just after  `\mainmatter`, I think.

Comment: @Bernard then i get a undefined control sequence (i already included the package setspace)
This is the exact error message:
l.40 \setspace
              {1.5}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

'\setstretch{1.5}' works. Are there any downsides?

Comment: @Leon D: Sorry, 'twas  a *lapsus calami*.  I meant `\setstretch{1.5}`.

Comment: As always, simplest way is to do the title page standalone and include the pdf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @Bernard said in his comment: First import `setspace`, and then use `\setstretch{1.5}` before your main part and everything works fine. Thank you!

Comment: A note on `\linespread{1.05}`: See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31074/164314). So, if your template uses Palatino or its clone, then you probably want 1.5*1.05=1.575, i.e., `\setstretch{1.575}`.